# Any intranet accelerators for Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any software out there that assists in creating an intranet-style proxy for Google’s AppEngine? The problem I’m trying to solve is to enable corporate users to:
1.  Enjoy a more responsive experience when plugged into their LAN, 
and
2.  Remain productive during Internet outages.

I'm not talking about a simple HTTP proxy server here... but instead something which can *serve* LAN users on behalf of GAE. Is this sort of thing at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to run an App Engine app on your own infrastructure, you probably want to check out [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) or [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/). It sounds like you're looking for something that does even more than that, though - serving local users when disconnected, while still running on Google's infrastructure as well? I'm not sure how something like that would work, or if it's even possible. It would certainly need to be explicitly dealt with by the app, since there's no general way to handle partitioning in a database in a completely consistent fashion.

Comment: Great response - thanks Nick. Both TyphoonAE and AppScale appear to have their own data-layer implementations, which is a pity. I was hoping to be able to implement something of a cache/accelerator within the LAN, but still use GAE as the primary. Like you said, this will take very specific coding.

Comment: How would you do that if you want it to function during an internet outage?